# Array comparison in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, compare

Is there any built in Matlab function that can compare arrays in the following manner?

```
function comparison = elementcompare(array1,array2)

comparison=logical(true);
for i=1:length(array1)
    if ~any(array1(i)==array2)
        comparison=logical(false);
    end
end
```

This comparison, which returns true if every element of array1 can be found in array2, seems pretty basic but I was not able to find it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most straightforward way is to use [`ismember`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html):

```
comparison = all(ismember(array1(:), array2(:)));
```

It can also be done with [`setdiff`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/setdiff.html):

```
comparison = isempty(setdiff(array1(:), array2(:)));
```

As usual, [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) can do the job:

```
comparison = all(any(bsxfun(@eq, array1(:).', array2(:))));
```

Or even [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/unique.html):

```
comparison = numel(unique([array1(:); array2(:)]))==numel(unique(array2(:)));
```